# Smart Map - Setting single map with multiple pins

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have a Smart Map field in a section and am trying to output multiple results (pins) to a single map.

This code will output multiple maps (one map per pin)

```
{% for mapEntry in craft.entries.section('markets') %}
{% set options = {
    height: 500,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
    markerOptions: {
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
    },
    infoWindowOptions: {
        maxWidth: 200
    }
} %}

{% set locations = craft.entries.section('markets').marketAddress.find() %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}

{% endfor %}
```

So essentially I am trying to get the `{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}` outside the for loop.

```
{% set locations = '' %}
{% set options = '' %}
{% for mapEntry in craft.entries.section('markets') %}
{% set options = {
    height: 500,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
    markerOptions: {
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
    },
    infoWindowOptions: {
        maxWidth: 200
    }
} %}
{% set locations = craft.entries.section('markets').marketAddress.find() %}
{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this only results in a single pin (most recent entry).

Can't get my head around this. Any assistance most welcome.

Comment: Turns out this code works fine. Adjusting zoom level showed proper results. Ahem!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out! For any other folks just passing by, a zoom level of `14` is extremely close. The maximum is `16`, which practically shows your front doorstep. (Conversely, `1` is a distant view from outer space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/render-a-map-in-twig/), `locations` has to be an array of elements or an ElementCriteriaModel
if you want to display multiple markers.

```
{% set mapEntries = craft.entries.section('markets') %}
{{ craft.smartMap.map(mapEntries, options) }}
```